# Accessing object within JSON - Ionic/typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, object, ionic-framework

Trying to access an object within a (remote) JSON file. Have successfully got part of the JSON but cannot for the life of my work out how to get the object **fruits/type**. As I understand it, I need to use something like **fruits[0].type** but cannot work out how to do this within the existing code. Any help appreciated.

```
{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "fruitname",
   
    "timestamp":
    {
        "time": 1647213439560
    },
    "fruits":
    {
        "type":
        {
            "Banana": "yellow",
            "Orange'": "orange",
            "Apple": "green"
        },
        "stats":
        {
            "eaten": 9,
            "dislike": 0
        }
    }
    }
```

I'm using this code:

```
getdata() {
    this.httpService.get(this.apiurl).subscribe(res => {
        this.items = Object.keys(res).map(function(key) {
          return res[key];
        });
    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
       }
      );
    }
```

and with this I can get the timestamp but need to get the **fruits**, **type** and **stats**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: `const banana = res.fruits.type.Banana`, `const typesAsPairs = Object.entries(res.fruits.type)`, `const onlyTypeValues = Object.entries(res.fruits.type).map(([key, value]) => value)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the type of **"res"** as **"any"** like

```
subscribe((res:any)=>{
let fruit_type=res.fruits.type;
...
});
```

2. Your code may change according to your needs.